# Show intellisense for .net framework version

Tags: resharper

I have a project that is configure for .Net Framework 4, hence I don´t want to see suggestions for newer frameworks. Is it possible to configure Resharper to show only intellisense for certain .Net Framework version?

Comment: At least give an example.

Comment: Hi what kind of an example?

Comment: "I don't want to see suggestions for newer frameworks", and what do you see exactly? As far as I know there is no such thing.

Comment: Resharper should obey the current project's target framework.

Answer (score 1):

Select your project in the Solution Explorer, press <kbd>F4</kbd> to open its properties window, change the 'C# Language Level' to the version of C# you are using (C# 4.0 or C# 5.0)

[image]